# CodeIgniter call_hook('post_controller_constructor') exits

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have inherited a webapp using CodeIgniter
I am trying to get it to run locally on my mac

when I try to go to http://localhost ,i can see via the debug logs i connect ok to the db
but when i get to this line in the file CodeIgniter.php it just stops. I see the first error_log, but then nothing

```
error_log("(".__LINE__.") ".__FILE__." -->".__METHOD__." \n");
$EXT->call_hook('post_controller_constructor');
error_log("(".__LINE__.") ".__FILE__." -->".__METHOD__." \n");
```

There is nothing in php_error.log

The browser says "This site can’t be reached"

I am a total noob to CodeIgniter

This code was ftp'd from a working server.

Would love any suggestions on how to debug this further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an error in your hooks that stop the execution?

Did you check those in the application/hooks folder?

Comment: yes, thank you. it was ssl.php in the hooks folder that was blowing up